# Display json data page wise in corona

Tags: coronasdk

I am retrieving data from JSON, but whole of the Data are displayed on my page,
but i want to display it page wise, for eg. 1 to 10 on first page,
and as the user presses the button, rest of the record are showed, i was working 
on that, but could not solve it, Is there are any concept of Paging in Corona,
Or please provide help regarding this issue, thanks..

Here is my json data structure:

```
My code for displaying JSON data:



 local test=json.decode(event.response)
    local datas=test.data
    for name, users in pairs(datas) do
       for names, usernames in pairs(users ) do
          for tag,value in pairs(usernames) do
           cid=value.customerid
           cname=value.customername
           print(cname)
           print(cid)
          end
       end
    end
```

---

this is my json data which is to be displayed page wise

```
{
    "status":"success",
    "data":{
    "marks":[
    {
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Amit",
    "last_name":"Sharma",
    "country_id":"20",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
   }
},
   {
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Amit",
    "last_name":"Yadav",
    "country_id":"21",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
    {
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Pankaj",
    "last_name":"Shukla",
    "country_id":"22",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
    {
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Abhishek",
    "last_name":"Tiwari",
    "country_id":"25",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
    {
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Kashif",
    "last_name":"Khan",
    "country_id":"20",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
{
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Ankit",
    "last_name":"Sharma",
    "country_id":"19",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
{
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Rahul",
    "last_name":"Vishwakarma",
    "country_id":"27",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
{
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Amit",
    "last_name":"Tiwari",
    "country_id":"30",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
{
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Amit",
    "last_name":"Sharma",
    "country_id":"78",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
},
{
    "Marks":{
    "first_name":"Amit",
    "last_name":"Sharma",
    "country_id":"23",
    "Physics":"50",
    "Chemistry":"35",
    "Mathematics":"40"
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

Comment: why don't you just loop it by 10 instead of looping it all

Comment: Can you please give me some hint how can i use loop here.

Comment: can you provide a link of your json data

Comment: I have added my json data here..you can see above ... please tell how to apply parsing and paging here... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a hint on how you can get your JSON data i just get the first and last name here i just copy your json data and put it on a textfile name data

```
local json = require "json"
local txt
local path = system.pathForFile( "data.txt", system.ResourceDirectory )
data = {}
local file = io.open( path, "r" )
if file then
       -- read all contents of file into a string
       txt = file:read( "*a" )
       io.close( file ) -- close the file after using it
end

local t = json.decode (txt)



for i = 1, table.getn(t["data"]["marks"]), 1 do

print(t["data"]["marks"][i]["Marks"]["first_name"])
print(t["data"]["marks"][i]["Marks"]["last_name"])


end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code above is just dumping prints to the console. I assume that in the end you want to actually display it on the screen.  I would recommend using a widget.newTableView() and let the system handle the scrolling for you.

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newTableView.html